# Working with Pointers and Strcpy in C

Tags: c, linux

I'm fairly new to the concept of pointers in C. Let's say I have two variables:

```
char *arch_file_name;
char *tmp_arch_file_name;
```

Now, I want to copy the value of `arch_file_name` to `tmp_arch_file_name` and add the word "tmp" to the end of it. I'm looking at them as strings, so I have:

```
strcpy(&tmp_arch_file_name, &arch_file_name);
strcat(tmp_arch_file_name, "tmp");
```

However, when `strcat()` is called, both of the variables change and are the same. I want one of them to **change** and the other to **stay intact**. I have to use pointers because I use the names later for the fopen(), rename() and delete() functions. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you pointed them at the appropriate buffers? Have you accidentally pointed them at the *same* buffer?

Comment: When I do
 
printf("tmp: %s\n", tmp_arch_file_name);
    

printf("original tmp: %s\n", arch_file_name);

they both have the same value

Comment: Do you realize that when you declare `char *arch_file_name;` you *have not* reserved any space in memory to put the string? Do you know how to reserve some space for it? (paxdiablo's method below is the simplest and safest, but there are other ways...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is:

```
strcpy(tmp_arch_file_name, arch_file_name);
strcat(tmp_arch_file_name, "tmp");
```

You are just copying the pointers (and other random bits until you hit a 0 byte) in the original code, that's why they end up the same.

As shinkou correctly notes, make sure `tmp_arch_file_name` points to a buffer of sufficient size (it's not clear if you're doing this in your code).  Simplest way is to do something like:

```
char buffer[256];
char* tmp_arch_file_name = buffer;
```

Comment: Just one note: before doing `strcat`, make sure you have enough space to hold the resulting string in `tmp_arch_file_name`.

Comment: I did that and I could've sworn it gave me Segmentation fault error the first time I tried it! But it's working now... It was probably somewhere else I was getting that error. Thanks.

Comment: @programmer93 It did. And it did it because those pointer are not pointed at valid memory. I think we have found the root cause of your trouble.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to make sure those pointers actually point to valid memory. As they are, they're either NULL pointers or arbitrary values, neither of which will work very well:

```
char *arch_file_name = "somestring";
char tmp_arch_file_name[100]; // or malloc
```

Then you `cpy` and `cat`, but with the pointers, not pointers-to-the-pointers that you currently have:

```
strcpy (tmp_arch_file_name, arch_file_name);  // i.e., no "&" chars
strcat (tmp_arch_file_name, "tmp");
```

Note that there is no bounds checking going on in this code - the sample doesn't need it since it's clear that all the strings will fit in the allocated buffers.

However, unless you totally control the data, a more robust solution would check sizes before blindly copying or appending. Since it's not directly related to the question, I won't add it in here, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: What the ? I can only assume, given the basic nature of my error, that I was posting while inebriated :-)  Thanks for that, @Olaf, I've fixed them up.

Answer (score 2):

Before you use pointers, you need to *allocate* memory. Assuming that `arch_file_name` is assigned a value already, you should calculate the length of the result string, allocate memory, do `strcpy`, and then `strcat`, like this:

```
char *arch_file_name = "/temp/my.arch";
// Add lengths of the two strings together; add one for the \0 terminator:
char * tmp_arch_file_name = malloc((strlen(arch_file_name)+strlen("tmp")+1)*sizeof(char));
strcpy(tmp_arch_file_name, arch_file_name);
//    ^ this   and   this ^ are pointers already; no ampersands!
strcat(tmp_arch_file_name, "tmp");

// use tmp_arch_file_name, and then...
free(tmp_arch_file_name);
```

Comment: No, no, no, no, no, a thousand times, no :-) `sizeof(char)` is _ALWAYS_ 1, no need to multiply.

Comment: @paxdiablo The last time I checked, multiplying *anything* by one does not change things, does it :-) It never hurts to multiply by `sizeof` simply to form a good habit.

Comment: @paxdiablo Well, he could try `*sizeof(*tmp_arch_file_name)` which is just as redundant for `char` buffers but is robust against changing the type of the pointer.

Comment: No, it doesn't _hurt,_ I just don't consider it good form, since it clogs up the code unnecessarily.

Comment: IMHO, if you see production code with many lines containing allocations and sizeofs, it is easier to read the intention of code without worrying about a type's size. It remains consistent whether you use an int or any other type latter. It is similar to the practice of suggesting to always use {} even if your while or if is a single line, just because you might have to add lines latter and forget parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` operator is the *address-of* operator, that is it returns the address of a variable. However using it on a pointer returns the address of where the pointer is stored, not what it points to.